# Issue with loading jquery and boostrap (possible app.js & webpack.mix.js issue)

Tags: laravel, webpack

I'm trying to create a dropdown using bootstrap but the dropdown doesnt open. I fixed it by adding `jquery` and `boostrap` css & js cdn links to my header and footer. My understanding is that both `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` are supposed to be included in `app.js`. However when I look at my `app.js` I dont see code for either and it doesn't look right.

I created a custom `test.js` file that is suppose to show an alert on page load, and when a button is clicked but I get `$ is undefined` unless I combine `jquery.js` and `test.js` into one file, again shouldn't jquery alreayd be loaded in `app.js`

test.js

```
$(function() {
    alert('test');
}

function test() {
    alert('worked');
}
```

webpack.js

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .styles(['resources/assets/css/approve.css'], 'public/css/approve.css')
    .scripts(['resources/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js',
        'resources/assets/js/test.js'],
        'public/js/vendor.js');
```

app.js

https://pastebin.com/rnWkQBmz

footer.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/vendor.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

bootstrap.js

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}
```

full bootstrap.js https://pastebin.com/274biWYp

app.scss

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

Am I correct in my thinking that if `app.js` combines `bootstrap.js` and `jquery.js` and I shouldnt have to include them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem. Somehow my `app.js` in `resources/assets/js` got overwritten and had a function inside of it so I copied and pasted the original one from laravel https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/app.js

Answer (score 0):

> I had the same problem once

simply remove `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');` from you

`bootstrap.js` and transpile the code again. you should add `jquery` before `app.js` to get it working